# UIAlertController not displaying Alert in iOS 8.4.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uialertcontroller

I have presented view controller using

```
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In the presented view controller I am trying to present UIAlertcontroller, it is not presenting also showing warning in the console in iOS 8.4.1

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    UIAlertAction *extend_action = nil;
    UIAlertAction *ok_action  = nil;

    UIAlertController *controller = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Call will begin"
                                                                        message:msg_str   
                                                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    extend_action = [UIAlertAction  actionWithTitle:@"Extend Time?" 
                                              style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                            handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) { 
                                                 // Method.
                                            }];
    ok_action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" 
                                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault                            
                                       handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) { 
                                    }];                        
    [controller addAction:extend_action];
    [controller addAction:ok_action];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

Attempt to present UIAlertController on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy! 
I am getting above warning.

Comment: As the message states, your trying to present the alert into a view that isn't visible.

Comment: How are you creating the alert? Can you show your `UIAlertController` code and your `UIAlertAction`s that you added to your `UIAlertController`?

Comment: @DogCoffee, then what i need to modify in presenting alert controller.

Comment: Need more code, also why don't you upgrade to iOS 9 and also use Swift??

Comment: Seems fine, only thing i can think of is this is being called in VC B (for example) while VC A is on screen - where are you call this method from ? In a modal dismiss or something ??

Answer (score 3):

Try presenting it on main queue:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```

Comment: This is in swift, i used objective-C. It is not working. i am getting same warning message and my alert controller is not presented.

Comment: please post some code showing creation of UIAlertController

Comment: your code works fine. I tried it. by the way where r u writing this code?

Comment: I am calling in my own method, i got to know the reason why it is not presenting because first view controller is presented on that view i am trying to present one more view (alert controller), so it is not presenting.

Comment: this error comes when self.view is not on screen when the call is made

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91822/discussion-between-ianurag-and-user3898700).

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your method with a delay or in main thread to present the alert controller
Here is the example

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self presentAlert];
});
```

}

```
- (void)presentAlert
{

UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Info" message:@"Hello alet controller" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIActionSheetStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}];

UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIActionSheetStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}];

[alert addAction:ok];
[alert addAction:cancel];

  [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

You can use

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
[self presentAlert];
});
```

Hope this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

You have to show alert on viewDidAppear method.. in viewDidLoad method view is not yet appeared and that is why your alert is getting visible